# Git: Show every line added by user in current branch

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I would like a certain 'non-technical' person to have a better idea of what I am actually doing when I work on a certain github project.  I would like to create a text file with ALL the code I have added to the main branch of this project.  I want to put it in a text editor and scroll down all of it, for however many screens.  That's basically what I want, for this reason, a 'number of lines' or 'number of characters' stat would not have the same impact.

Specifically, what I want to show is:
(first choice) all the lines ever added by me, even if they were removed later.

(second choice) all the lines I contributed in the latest version (we only have one branch)

Is there a way to do this, or at least just print out all the lines in the current branch? (I wrote over 90% of them anyway)

I know that by itself this is not terribly useful, but I feel this is one script away from something more useful such as i.e. number of lines.

Background ->
I am relatively new to Git, I am using it from the command line on Windows.  I have some linux experience so this doesn't bother me too much.  I am also using Github for this project and I have access to the github for windows client (though I don't really use it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
git show $(git rev-list --author="Your Name" HEAD)
```

This shows diffs, not "added lines", but diffs are more meaningful. No automated procedure can decide whether a line that was replaced with a different line should be considered an addition or just a modification.

Comment: Agreed that addition/modification would be very difficult to determine automatically.  This command appears to show additions, deletions, AND existing lines.  I am fine with showing existing lines once, but will this command print the entire contents of a file every time the file is modified via commit? I would rather not do that.  Still this is a big help though, as a place to start.  Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't print full contents, just a regular diff (lines added and removed, with a few of the unchanged neighboring lines included to provide context). You can eliminate the context lines by adding -U0. Somebody who can't even read a diff demands to know what a programmer is doing? Show them a hexdump of some random file, let them look at it until they go away.

Comment: This answer seemed to work.  It produced an output very similar in size to the other answer which seemed to work.  Thank you very much for coming back and providing even more information after my comment!  Although I would like to vote up and accept both answers, I am not sure what to do but I feel I should accept this answer since it came first.  If anyone is reading this, please vote up the other answer as well, as long as it looks right.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the following to get a "minimal" (with zero lines of context instead of three) patch of all your changes:

```
for h in $(git --no-pager log --author='name' --format='%H' HEAD); do git --no-pager diff-tree -U0 $h; done >mychanges.txt
```

`mychanges.txt` should give the "non-technical" person some idea of what you've done; all they really need to understand is that lines starting with `+` are lines you added and lines starting with `-` are lines you deleted. Walk through a few diffs for some files and they'll get the hang of it and should be able to read the rest of the file on their own.

Comment: This answer seemed to work.  It produced an output very similar in size to the other answer which seemed to work.  Thanks for providing the exact command to type in!  Although I would like to vote up and accept both answers, I am going to accept the other answer since it was posted first.  However if anyone is reading this, I hope they vote up both answers, assuming we haven't overlooked anything.